How do exchanges calculate IVs of American-style (stock) options?
As stated in the title, how do exchanges (such as NASDAQ) actually calculate the implied volatilities and Greeks of American-style stock options? From my perspective this is relevant if I'd like to replicate or validate their IVs.
For example, if I visit the NASDAQ page I see IVs and Greeks for AAPL. I am assuming that they do not run heavy numerical simulations to convert the prices into de-Americanized IVs?
My best guess is that they run a relatively light tree or finite-difference routine in the background to arrive at the IVs. However I cannot find a white paper or methodology document on this. Would somebody be able to shed more light on this?

hoep all good
This document suggests a path used by a market leading firm in this space:
https://voladynamics.com/pdf/vanillaTalk_CU_website.pdf
details on these LR trees can be found here:
https://www.macroption.com/leisen-reimer-formulas/

All good, hope with you too. Thanks for the links. The dividend modelling paper is comprehensive. I'm not there yet though, just assuming div yields for simplicity. I've been reading this paper on de-Americanization (https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.06181) which I found interesting, and suspect this type of algo is used as well by exchanges / mm? As a next step I was wondering if the accuracy can be improved by using Edgeworth binomial trees (https://core.ac.uk/reader/6955950) in the de-Americanization process.

For anybody who is interested in this, I managed to find this brief methodology document from/by the CBOE from 2021:
https://cdn.cboe.com/api/global/us_indices/governance/Cboe_American_Style_Options_Implied_Volatility_Calculations_Methodology.pdf
So it seems a binomial tree flavour is the 'standard' for calculating IVs from American options.
